# TypeError: Cannot add property transform, object is not extensible

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a `Clock` component where the divs represent the clock's hands. The `hours, minutes, and seconds` should rotate to a certain degree amount, when updated to the current time.

`updateClockHandsToCurrentTimeHandler` is called every second by `setInterval` when the component is mounted.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const clock = {
    width: '20rem',
    height: '20rem',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRadius: '50%'
}

const x = '100'
const clockFace = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    transform: `translate(${x}px)`
}
const hours = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '6px',
    transformOrigin: '100%',
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
    background: 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 30% black 30%, black 30%, black 100%)'
}

const minutes = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '6px',
    transformOrigin: '100%',
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
    background: 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10% black 30%, black 10%, black 100%)'
}

const seconds = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '6px',
    transformOrigin: '100%',
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
    background: 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10% black 30%, black 10%, black 100%)'
}

class Clock extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.secondsElement = React.createRef('.seconds');
        this.minutesElement = React.createRef('.minutes');
        this.hoursElement = React.createRef('.hours');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(this.updateClockHandsToCurrentTimeHandler, 1000);
        this.updateClockHandsToCurrentTimeHandler();
  }

    updateClockHandsToCurrentTimeHandler = () => {
        // get the current time
        const now = new Date();

        // break it down to hours, minutes and seconds
        const seconds = now.getSeconds();
        const minutes = now.getMinutes();
        const hours = now.getHours();

        // calculate the rotation of each clock hand in degrees
        const secondsRotationDegrees = (seconds / 60) * 360; // (60/60) * 360
        const minutesRotationDegrees = (minutes / 60) * 360 + (seconds/60) * 6; // ((60/60) * 360) + ((60/60) * 6 )
        const hoursRotationDegrees = (hours/ 12) * 360 + (minutes / 60) * 30;

        this.secondsElement.transform = `rotate(${secondsRotationDegrees+90}deg)`;
        this.minutesElement.transform = `rotate(${minutesRotationDegrees+90}deg)`;
        this.hoursElement.transform = `rotate(${hoursRotationDegrees+90}deg)`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={clock}>
                <div style={clockFace}>
                    <div style={hours}></div>
                    <div style={minutes}></div>
                    <div style={seconds}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

With my current code, I receive the TypeError pointing to this line `this.secondsElement.transform = rotate(${secondsRotationDegrees+90}deg)`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish the task? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly you need to associate the `ref`s to your `div` elements.
- Secondly, to access the element you need to use `.current`.
- Finally to apply styles to refs you need to use `.current.style.transform`

**Like this:**

```js
updateClockHandsToCurrentTimeHandler = () => {
        // get the current time
        const now = new Date();

        // break it down to hours, minutes and seconds
        const seconds = now.getSeconds();
        const minutes = now.getMinutes();
        const hours = now.getHours();

        // calculate the rotation of each clock hand in degrees
        const secondsRotationDegrees = (seconds / 60) * 360; // (60/60) * 360
        const minutesRotationDegrees = (minutes / 60) * 360 + (seconds/60) * 6; // ((60/60) * 360) + ((60/60) * 6 )
        const hoursRotationDegrees = (hours/ 12) * 360 + (minutes / 60) * 30;

        this.secondsElement.current.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsRotationDegrees+90}deg)`;
        this.minutesElement.current.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesRotationDegrees+90}deg)`;
        this.hoursElement.current.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursRotationDegrees+90}deg)`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={clock}>
                <div style={clockFace}>
                    <div ref={hoursElement} style={hours}></div>
                    <div ref={minutesElement} style={minutes}></div>
                    <div ref={secondsElement} style={seconds}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```